# Galleria image limit?

Tags: jquery, galleria

I know I read somewhere that Galleria has a limit of only 100 images per slideshow, I just can't seem to find where I read that... Got a client who wants 108 images per slideshow. any idea how to overwrite this?

http://galleria.aino.se/

http://getsatisfaction.com/galleria

Comment: are you sure? It doesn't say anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: There's no limit that I know of.

Comment: http://getsatisfaction.com/galleria/topics/want_to_load_all_images_instead_the_limit_of_100_any_solutions i don't think this is where i read it but it's mentioned here too

Comment: Well I have 105 images in my gallery and it's grand. Sorry I was wrong! Thanks so much for clearing this up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [optimalization page](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/references/optimize/) for Galleria:

> There are no limits to how many images you can add, but after 30 it can clog the pipes on load, especially in IE. Use a reasonable amount of images at first, then try the .load(), .splice() and .push() methods to add/remove image data on the fly.

Comment: I'm running into the scenario where Galleria starts lagging pretty heavily if I run .push() a hundred times. It seems as if it's reiterating through the entire thumbnails. Is there a way to pause until everything is loaded?

Comment: Don't know you setup, but if you're adding multiple images at once, you can just supply unlimited arguments to the .push() method: http://galleria.io/docs/api/methods/#push-element1-elementn

Comment: Yea - I was able to figure that out but I ended up refining it a bit more by changing the push method to not always refresh the thumbnails. This led to a pretty big win performance win and let me control it a bit more.